# Riemannian Optimization Tutorial?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, optimization

Looking for a good quick guide about Riemannian optimization, from an applied perspective such as machine learning. Referrals to easy to read references would be really appreciated.

Comment: Suvrit Sra has many interesting papers http://suvrit.de/

Comment: Thanks. Day you see them as a good way to get introduced to the topic too?

Comment: This depends in your background, assuming you know a bit about optimization (gradient descent) and Riemannian geometry (exponential map), then yes.

Comment: Then the next question would be where is a good start for Riemannian geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recommend you see homepage of P.-A. Absil:https://sites.uclouvain.be/absil/#publi

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an introductory book for Riemannian optimization, designed for applied mathematicians and engineers:

*An introduction to optimization on smooth manifolds*

http://www.nicolasboumal.net/book

Chapters 3 and 5 are a stand-alone introduction to Riemannian geometry for the special case of embedded submanifolds of linear spaces. This covers many usual applications of Riemannian optimization, and allows to give precise definitions and full proofs without the need for charts and atlases. Chapters 4 and 6 focus on algorithms. Chapter 7 details some manifolds of interest. Later chapters look at more advanced topics.